# unable to connect to the internet through my Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: wireless

unable to connect to the Internet through my Ubuntu 13.10

```
lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub 
[8086:2a00] (rev 03) 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary) 
[8086:2a02] (rev 03) 00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary) 
[8086:2a03] (rev 03) 00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 
[8086:2834] (rev 03) 00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 
[8086:2835] (rev 03) 00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 
[8086:283a] (rev 03) 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) HD Audio Controller 
[8086:284b] (rev 03) 00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 1 
[8086:283f] (rev 03) 00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 2 
[8086:2841] (rev 03) 00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) PCI Express Port 3 
[8086:2843] (rev 03) 00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 
[8086:2830] (rev 03) 00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 
[8086:2831] (rev 03) 00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 
[8086:2832] (rev 03) 00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 
[8086:2836] (rev 03) 00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge 
[8086:2448] (rev f3) 00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801HM (ICH8M) LPC Interface Controller 
[8086:2815] (rev 03) 00:1f.1 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) IDE Controller 
[8086:2850] (rev 03) 00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [IDE mode] 
[8086:2828] (rev 03) 00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801H (ICH8 Family) SMBus Controller 
[8086:283e] (rev 03) 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8039 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4353] (rev 15) 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 wireless uses proprietary drivers. Temporarily connect your system to the internet using an Ethernet cable. You should have the opportunity to install it by using the additional drivers application. Once installed your wireless connection should function normally.

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you link me with a tutorial on how to connect my system to the internet using an Ethernet cable, i have another laptop running window 7, how do i connect the 2 togther?

Comment: @user257509 There is no need to connect your laptops together. You should be able to connect via ethernet cable to your router or cablemodem. It will be obvious where to plug it in if you have one.  Your lspci -nn output indicates that you have a Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8039 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller.